# How to add dynamic description to SharePoint 2010 Logo / Title area

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am working on a SP2010 site Master Template. I would like to have the information from the Site Settings -> Title, Description and Icon show up in the header area. I can get the title to show up site-wide along with the logo, however, the description changes when i go to say a Library for example.

If I try and use this:

```
<div class="s4-pagedescription" tabindex="0" >
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageDescription" runat="server"> </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
```

...it changes when I head into a list or sub section... I want the Description found in Site Settings to be the determining site description.

```
<table class="s4-titletable" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="s4-titlelogo"><SharePoint:SPLinkButton runat="server" NavigateUrl="~site/" id="onetidProjectPropertyTitleGraphic">
          <SharePoint:SiteLogoImage name="onetidHeadbnnr0" id="onetidHeadbnnr2" LogoImageUrl="/Style Library/fsimages/logo.png" runat="server"/>
        </SharePoint:SPLinkButton></td>
      <td class="s4-titletext"><h1> 
          <!-- This is giving me the Title across the site no problem --->
          <asp:SiteMapPath runat="server" id="SiteMapPath1"></asp:SiteMapPath>
        </h1>
        <br/>

        <!-- HOW DO I GET THIS DESCRPTION DYNAMICALLY? -->

        <h2>(replace this with code to get description)</h2></td>
      <td class="s4-socialdata-notif"><SharePoint:DelegateControl ControlId="GlobalSiteLink3" Scope="Farm" runat="server"/></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will work in a master page but on a page layout I once used the "ProjectProperty" tag.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
<h1>
        Welcome to site: <SharePoint:ProjectProperty runat="server" Property="Title"> </SharePoint:ProjectProperty>!
</h1>
</asp:Content>
```

I think you can replace the "Title" with "Description"